# ImportError: cannot import name 'nsprefixes' Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I am getting this error while importing nsprefixes from docx library.

```
from docx import nsprefixes
```

Any idea on How to resolve this issue?

Comment: `docx` is best used in python2 instead of python3. When installed for python 2.7, the above code works flawlessly.

Comment: I tried with python 2.7 as well, it still gives me the same error : "ImportError: cannot import name nsprefixes"

Comment: Did you make a file in your working directory called `docx.py`? If so, rename it.

Comment: @glibdud no I do not have any such file in my working directory.

Comment: Did you do `sudo -H python -m pip install docx` ?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj yes I tried, but no luck.

Comment: Do you have `conda` installed? Is `python -m pip -V` working? If yes, what does it print?

Comment: I dont have conda.
It prints: pip 9.0.3 from /home/lab-fateh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nsprefixes` is an object from the obsolete, much prior version of `python-docx` here:
https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx

If you want to use that code you'll need to uninstall the current package and install the very old one:

```
$ pip uninstall python-docx
$ pip install docx
```

Doing so is not generally recommended, but since you haven't mentioned anything about your use case I'll leave that decision to you.

That code base was completely re-written to create the current version, so the two are not compatible in any way.

There is a generally similar object in the new version under the name `nsmap`:

```
from docx.oxml.ns import nsmap
```

Which you can inspect here:
https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/oxml/ns.py

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have posted another question on python-docx which I saw u have answered a long time ago with old docx library which is not available anymore(thats the reason i posted this question). Could you please take some time and help me with that question. It'll be really helpful for me. 
Here's the link to that question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737926/how-to-split-text-read-from-a-docx-file-with-page-breaks-using-python3-docx 
Thanks